# Typescript wants more attributes than necessary for Paypal SDK

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to send a request with the help of [@paypal/checkout-server-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/checkout-server-sdk)

I am using nodejs with typescript.

```js
import paypal from '@paypal/checkout-server-sdk';
const paypalClient = new paypal.core.PayPalHttpClient(
  new paypal.core.SandboxEnvironment(
    String(process.env.CLIENT_ID),
    String(process.env.APP_SECRET)
  )
);

  const request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCreateRequest();
  request.requestBody({
    intent: 'CAPTURE',
    purchase_units: [
      {
        amount: {
          currency_code: 'EUR',
          value: ticketPriceString,
          breakdown: {
            item_total: {
              currency_code: 'EUR',
              value: ticketPriceString,
            },
          },
        },
        items: [
          {
            name: 'Ticket',
            unit_amount: {
              currency_code: 'EUR',
              value: ticketPriceString,
            },
            quantity: quantity,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  });
```

If i compile, i get following error:

```
src/paypal/paypal.ts:36:11 - error TS2740: Type '{ item_total: { currency_code: string; value: string; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'AmountBreakdown': discount, handling, insurance, shipping_discount, and 2 more.

36           breakdown: {
             ~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/paypal__checkout-server-sdk/lib/orders/lib.d.ts:58:5
    58     breakdown?: AmountBreakdown;
           ~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'breakdown' which is declared here on type 'AmountWithBreakdown'

src/paypal/paypal.ts:44:11 - error TS2741: Property 'category' is missing in type '{ name: string; unit_amount: { currency_code: string; value: string; }; quantity: string; }' but required in type 'Item'.

 44           {
              ~
 45             name: 'Ticket',
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
 50             quantity: quantity,
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 51           },
    ~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/paypal__checkout-server-sdk/lib/orders/lib.d.ts:479:5
    479     category: Category;
            ~~~~~~~~
    'category' is declared here.


Found 2 errors in the same file, starting at: src/paypal/paypal.ts:36
```

The interface of `AmountBreakdown` looks like this: (source: node_modules@types\paypal__checkout-server-sdk\lib\payments\lib.d.ts)

```js
// https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#definition-amount_breakdown
export interface AmountBreakdown {
    discount: Money;
    handling: Money;
    insurance: Money;
    item_total: Money;
    shipping_discount: Money;
    shipping: Money;
    tax_total: Money;
}
```

If i write the same as plain javascript it works, but my project is in Typescript. How would you solve this?

**UPDATE**
Thanks for the replies :)
I fixed the error messages so far but now i have a problem at importing the `Category` enum. How can i import this?

```js
import paypal from '@paypal/checkout-server-sdk';
import { Category } from '@paypal/checkout-server-sdk/lib/orders/lib';

const paypalClient = new paypal.core.PayPalHttpClient(
  new paypal.core.SandboxEnvironment(
    String(process.env.CLIENT_ID),
    String(process.env.APP_SECRET)
  )
);

const createOrderSDK = async (
  ticketPriceCentBrutto: number,
  eventID: string
) => {
  console.log('in paypal.createOrderSDK');

  const ticketPriceString = convertNumberToString(ticketPriceCentBrutto);
  const quantity = '1';
  const request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCreateRequest();
  request.prefer('return=representation'); //what does this do?
  request.requestBody({
    intent: 'CAPTURE',
    purchase_units: [
      {
        amount: {
          currency_code: 'EUR',
          value: ticketPriceString,
          breakdown: {
            item_total: {
              currency_code: 'EUR',
              value: ticketPriceString,
            },
            discount: {
              currency_code: 'EUR',
              value: '0.00',
            },
            handling: {
              currency_code: 'EUR',
              value: '0.00',
            },
            insurance: {
              currency_code: 'EUR',
              value: '0.00',
            },
            shipping_discount: {
              currency_code: 'EUR',
              value: '0.00',
            },
            shipping: {
              currency_code: 'EUR',
              value: '0.00',
            },
            tax_total: {
              currency_code: 'EUR',
              value: '0.00',
            },
          },
        },
        items: [
          {
            name: 'Ticket',
            category: Category.DIGITAL_GOODS,
            unit_amount: {
              currency_code: 'EUR',
              value: ticketPriceString,
            },
            quantity: quantity,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  });

  return;
};
```

And this is the error message:

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:97
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\joshua\Documents\Business\kinkyShadesTicketing\ticketing\node_modules\@paypal\checkout-server-sdk\lib\orders\lib' imported from C:\Users\joshua\Documents\Business\kinkyShadesTicketing\ticketing\dist\paypal\paypal.js
Did you mean to import @paypal/checkout-server-sdk/lib/orders/lib.js?
```

adding an `.js` at the end of the import does not do the trick.

Comment: Just provide the category property.

Comment: Doesn't it make sense to try it without `breakdown`? You seem to have only partial information there, that is already specified directly into the `amount` object. And the typings seem to suggest that `breakdown` is optional itself, but if you provide it, you have to set all items in the interface.

Comment: The PayPal API requires breakdown when an items array is given

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answers. I updated my post now and got and error at importing the `Category` enum from paypal. How can I import this correctly?